# Massage with BeautifulSoup or clean with Regex

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Could someone tell me whats a better way to clean up bad HTML so BeautifulSoup can handle it - should one use the massage methods of BeautifulSoup  or clean it up using regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought I should reword my answer.

The built-in massages are good for light damage (extra whitespace, no closing slashes, etc). I would certainly try and get away with these before getting any more involved.

You can [pass in your own massages](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Sanitizing%20Bad%20Data%20with%20Regexps) and I would suggest you extend the default set:

```
import copy, re

myMassage = [(re.compile('<!-([^-])'), lambda match: '<!--' + match.group(1))]
myNewMassage = copy.copy(BeautifulSoup.MARKUP_MASSAGE)
myNewMassage.extend(myMassage)

BeautifulSoup(badString, markupMassage=myNewMassage)
# Foo<!--This comment is malformed.-->Bar<br />Baz
```

You're probably better off doing it this way as it all goes into one parsing pot, gaining BeautifulSoups optimisations... Although the runtime performance is probably pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Sanitizing%20Bad%20Data%20with%20Regexps), massage methods are just pairs of `(regular expression, replacement function)` so I don't think it's really a case of use massaging or regexps.

e.g. to tidy up malformed comments:

```
(re.compile('<!-([^-])'), lambda match: '<!--' + match.group(1))
```

If you look at the source of the `_feed` method in BeautifulSoup.py you will see that these are just run in sequence against the markup:

```
for fix, m in self.markupMassage:
  markup = fix.sub(m, markup)
```

So whilst you could do some regexp processing of your own before BeautifulSoup gets to see the markup you are probably better combining any additional tidying needed with the default builtin `MARKUP_MASSAGE` as shown in [Oli's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12870/oli) answer.